# Contact Image in listview is repeating when use a Baseadapter

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-contacts

I am building an application where I am storing all contact data in my sqlite database and populating that data in listview.

In the process the contact images are repeating and is displayed without any ordering.

**The adapter:**

```
private class ContactAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter

    {
        //Context context;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private Cursor c;
        private Context context;
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, c, from, to);
            this.c = c;
            this.context = context;
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ViewHolderContact viewHolder;

            //viewHolder = new ViewHolderContact();


            if(convertView==null)
            {
                viewHolder = new ViewHolderContact();

                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_contactlist, null);
                viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivimage);
                viewHolder.imgNext = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgnext);
                viewHolder.textView_Name = (TextView)convertView .findViewById(R.id.txtname);

            //  view.imgad.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                /*view.imgad.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                //view.imgad.setPadding(0,10,0,0);
                //view.imgad.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,100));
                //LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,90);
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,90);
                lp.setMargins(0,20,0,0);
                view.imgad.setLayoutParams(lp);
                 */
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            else
            {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolderContact)convertView.getTag();
            }

            this.c.moveToPosition(position);     
            String contactid = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            String contactname = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("contactname"));
            String contactnumber = this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("contactnumber"));
            String contactimage= this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("contactimage"));
            String isInstalled= this.c.getString(this.c.getColumnIndex("isInstalled"));


            //System.out.println("Isinstalled--->"+isInstalled);

            if(isInstalled.equals("Y"))
            {
                viewHolder.imgNext.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


            if (contactimage == null || contactimage.equals("")) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                    viewHolder.imageView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                }
                else {
                    viewHolder.imageView.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                }
                // If there is no image in the database "NA" is stored instead of a blob 
                // test if there more than 3 chars "NA" + a terminating char if more than
                // there is an image otherwise load the default
            }   //iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            else{   
                try {
                    Bitmap bmp=getContactBitmapFromURI(ContactList.this,Uri.parse(contactimage));
                    Bitmap round=getRoundedShape(bmp);
                    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(round);

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            viewHolder.textView_Name.setText(contactname);

            return convertView;                 

        }

        class ViewHolderContact {
            TextView textView_Name;
            ImageView imageView,imgNext;

        }

    }
```

c is the cursor instance

**The method getContactBitmapFromURI(Context context, Uri uri)**

```
public static Bitmap getContactBitmapFromURI(Context context, Uri uri) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStream input = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    if (input == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
}
```

Output:

[image: Instance 1]

When I scroll then the output becomes:

[image: Instance 2]

As you can see that the image is not properly displayed.They are repeating or/and disappearing.Please help.

Comment: Hi,I didn't accept because none of the answers satisfied my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this is the case of Image caching save your Image in a cache after decode it into `Bitmap`. Please go through the url to how to cache Image : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/cache-bitmap.html

Comment: I guess you are right,But caching of images is done mainly on urls and not uri s.I couldn't find any samples

Answer (score 0):

`Listview` reuse views. I think the problem is in the `cursor`. Maybe you can try setting the data first at the method `getItem()`. You can also try by doing `notifyDataChanged` when reached a certain position, if images change then is going to be a good point to start of.

Answer (score 0):

I think thats because of your if else part . In first case you are setting background of image and in second case you are setting src of image . The seImageBitmap() method set the bitmap as src . Change one of the case . Use same in both cases .So i suggest Use [Circle image view](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) for getting rounded image and use [UILoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) or [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
 to load the images . In that way you will get rid of caching and outofmemory error too ..

You can get image url fro uri like this

```
private String getPathFromUri(Uri uri) {
    String url = null;
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }, null, null, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        url = cursor.getString(0);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: Picasso loads url and contact images are uri like: content://com.android.contacts/display_photo/7--->contactimage

Comment: So get the Url from uri .Use this     
cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA }, null, null, null);
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) 
       String url= cursor.getString(0);